# How to: upgrade Laravel 4 beta without git clone?

Tags: laravel, updates, laravel-4, beta

Is there some way to upgrade **Laravel 4 beta** framework's base (or skeleton) **without** using `git clone`?

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge
```

But you are going to have a ton of collisions. I had a couple of projects in beta and it was just easier to move my code to a fresh install of Laravel 4.

Comment: I was create fresh install and move code to new project (easier and faster than it seemed). So update **skeleton** via 'composer update' is now working? Or composer just does not update **skeleton** files at all?

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see what you are saying. The way I install now, and I've done it a few times is...

Comment: oops.  
  
Continuing on...  
  
Create new directory, where you will run it from your development machine.  
  
`mkdir my-laravel.dev`  
`cd my-laravel.dev`  
`git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git .`  
`composer install` or `php composer.phar install`  
  
And you now have a fresh install ready to go Laravel 4.